# Return Condition from case statement in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

By searching a number of SO threads I am unable to write a query which returns the appropriate condition in the where clause. 
For example I have column Col1 which is `int` and a variable `var1` as `varchar` now I used below query but it is not working.

```
Where CASE WHEN var1 = '1' THEN (Col1 = 1)  
WHEN var1 = '2' THEN (Col1 = 2)  
ELSE AND (1= 1) 
END
```

It gives me `syntax error near '='`.

EDIT:

What If I want condition like

Col1 IN (condtions....)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it should be like;

```
Where Col1 = CASE WHEN var1 IN ('1','2') THEN var1 ELSE Col1 END
```

OR

```
Where Col1 = CASE  var1 WHEN  '1' THEN 1
                        WHEN  '2' THEN 2
             ELSE Col1 END ...
```

As a side note, if *`Col1 is nullable`* and `need to select` those as well then use;

```
Where Col1 is null OR 
             Col1 = CASE  var1 WHEN  '1' THEN 1
                        WHEN  '2' THEN 2
             ELSE Col1 END ...
```

Comment: Nullable can be checked with a `Col1 is null AND/OR` depending if he needs to filter or not.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I'm suggesting your up-voted answer should explain that too. My comment might not live on forever, and my answer might be ignored since you got two early upvotes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : Updated with `is null`

Comment: Thanks, but this will still return all NULL rows even if the condition explicitly asks for only Col1 = 1 or Col1 = 2. NULL values are typically only expected in the ELSE condition.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: my first CASE doesn't select col1 records where col1 is null.

Comment: @Kaf : Thanks for the response. But what if  Col1 IN CASE  var1 WHEN  '1' THEN (1,2)

Comment: you can also use it this way `Col1 = CASE  WHEN var1 IN  ('1','2') THEN var1
ELSE Col1 END`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Where Col1 = CASE WHEN var1 IN ('1','2') THEN var1 ELSE Col1 END, How do you write `Col1 in CASE WHEN..... It should return comma seperated values.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, If I am correctly understanding, you looking for this syntax `WHERE Col1 IN (SELECT CASE WHEN @x1 IN ('1','2') THEN @x1 ELSE 100 END)`  sort of?

Answer (score 2):

CASE is an expression that returns a value. It is not for control of flow logic like IF (though a similar keyword does work that way in some languages like VB). Try:

```
WHERE Col1 = CASE 
  WHEN var1 = '1' THEN 1
  WHEN var1 = '2' THEN 2 
  ELSE Col1
END
```

This will work as you've intended in the code you've tried *unless* Col1 is NULLable. One workaround is a magic value that can't appear in your data:

```
WHERE COALESCE(Col1, -1) = CASE
  ...
ELSE COALESCE(Col1, -1) END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the column outside of the case:

```
where Col1 = case when var1 = '1' then 1
                  when var1 = '2' then 2
             end
      OR (var1 != '1' AND var1 != '2')
```